# Problem with custom route

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been trying to create a route that maps to /Controller/Update/Customer/1 without success, I've tried

`routes.MapRoute("Scaffolding", "{controller}/{action}/{entity}/{id}");`

this is the first route, but even that way doesnt seem to match this request: http://localhost:7290/Scaffolding/Update/Customer/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing where the route is supposed to go to. an example is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Scaffolding",                                            
            "{controller}/{action}/{entity}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Scaffolding", action = "Update", entity = "Customer", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

You need to put the default parameters for that route in.